# Field can not be filtered in SOQL query call

Tags: apex, soql

Here is my SOQL code for finding records to update but it is generating a compiler error like "field 'Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c' can not be filtered in query call". Why can't I filter by this field?

```
string abc = obj[0].Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c;
string s ='%'+ abc + '%'; 
List<Chatter_Monitor_Policy__c> records = [SELECT Id, Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c from Chatter_Monitor_Policy__c where Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c Like:s and CreatedById =: UserInfo.getUserId()];
if(records.size()!=null)
{
  for(Integer i=0; i<records.size(); i++)
  {
    records[0].Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c = s;
    update records[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Textarea field types are filterable, but it needs to be done in the QueryResult

Quote from [SOAP API page](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

> **Textarea Field Type**
>
> Textarea fields contain text that can be longer
>   than 4000 bytes. Unlike string fields, textarea fields cannot be
>   specified in the WHERE clause of a queryString of a query() call. **To
>   filter records on this field, you must do so while processing records
>   in the QueryResult**. For fields with this restriction, its filterable
>   field in the Field type (described in the fields property of the
>   DescribeSObjectResult) is false.

So get the query results into a queryresult object, and filter over each of the returned objects.

Comment: Great find but do you have any examples on how to use QueryResult? I can't seem to find any examples on that link ...

Answer (score 13):

As indicated in the attached screenshot, check the "filterable" acces property of field in schema browser (Force.com IDE etc). This property indicates whether the field is filterable (true) or not (false). If true, then this field can be specified in the WHERE clause of a query string in a query() call. More details here : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects_describesobjectresult.htm

[image: Check the "filterable" acces property of field in schema browser]

Comment: Thanks. This was blocking me. You can also view the Schema in the Force Explorer AIR app if you don't want to use the Force.com IDE.

Answer (score 7):

If `Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c` is a text area then you can't filter by it, though if it truly is a key**word** (or short list of keywords) then it should just be a text field which you will be able to filter by.

Can you confirm what type of field you are using? If it is a text area then I'd suggest changing it to a text field if possible.

If you absolutely can't change the field type, then you're probably limited to selecting all of the records and performing the search in code — to do this you'll likely need to leverage a batch apex class to process the data volumes involved.

Comment: yes Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c is text area

Comment: That's your answer then — unfortunately you can't filter by text area fields in SOQL!

Comment: Then what is the exactly solution for that???

Comment: aah the problem is resolved here in the mean time, I was trying to figure out the answer :) SE rocks !

Comment: @KishanTrambadiya - does it really need to be a TextArea? Can you make it a Text field instead?

Comment: @KishanTrambadiya You need to make it something **other** than a text area!

Comment: @KishanTrambadiya Text and TextArea are two different field types. You can filter on Text; you cannot filter on TextArea. Changing `Chatter_Monitor_Policy_Keyword__c ` to a Text field will allow you to filter on it.

Comment: @metadaddy - i cant make it text field...

Comment: @KishanTrambadiya - well you can't filter on it then

Comment: @metadaddy - i asked question as i want any other alternative instead of this.

Comment: @KishanTrambadiya As metadaddy has mentioned with textarea we cant filter, if you need to filter you need to use textfield.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I hope my SOSL solution can help others. Actually, we can use **SOSL** as a workaround to turn Textarea field types into filterable/searchable field. See code sample below

```
String fieldValue = 'somevalue';
String fieldName = 'MyTextAreaField__c';
String query =  = 'FIND {"'+ fieldValue + '"}  RETURNING ' +
                  ' YourCustomObject__c (id, ' + fieldName + ' ) LIMIT 2000';
List<List<SObject>> searchList = Search.query(query);//Return List of SObject list
system.debug('Search result: ' + searchList[0]);//Get search result
if(searchList[0].size() > 0) {
   //You can cast your result and return other fields if needed
   List<YourCustomObject__c > objSearchResultsList = (List<YourCustomObject__c >) searchList[0];
   system.debug(fieldName +' with "' + objSearchResultsList[0].get(fieldName) + '" found. ');
 }
```

If your search result has record, the sample output will be:

```
Search result: (YourCustomObject__c:{Id=aeb02000000000LXXX, MyTextAreaField__c=somevalue})   
MyTextAreaField__c with "somevalue" found.
```