# query on anytype data type in salesforce?

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to query on history object. I want to query records which have specific old value on Lead Status Field.

I have already checked [Field can not be filtered in SOQL query call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1332/field-can-not-be-filtered-in-soql-query-call)

It is anytype datatype not text area as shown in Image.

[image]

Expected SOQL Query is (Query Editor):

```
SELECT  OldValue,Id, LeadId, CreatedDate FROM LeadHistory Where Field='Status' AND OldValue = 'New'
```

Error is:

```
[object Object]: LeadHistory Where Field='Status' AND OldValue = 'New' ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:84 field 'OldValue' can not be filtered in query call
```

Comment: It is not a text area type which is described in this.

Comment: read further down the post -->  check the "filterable" access property of the field

Comment: This isn't even a question. You don't ask anything. The field is not filterable.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thanks.
So my question is how to filter records based on OldValue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For OldValue and NewValue fields filter property is not available, so you can't filter on
  these fields
- I don't know what is your business scenario. but if you are sure
  about you will retrieve less than 50000 records in query. Then
  possible workaround can be filter records in apex.

..

```
 List<LeadHistory> leadHistoryList = new List<LeadHistory>();
    for (LeadHistory lh : [SELECT  OldValue,Id, LeadId, CreatedDate FROM LeadHistory Where Field='Status' LIMIT 50000])
    {
        if(lh.OldValue == 'New')
            leadHistoryList.add(lh);
    }
```